# What Authentication needed for GET project BIM360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

i try to get all project details from BIM360 by using this API.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/

but get a 403 forbiden :

```js
{
  "developerMessage": "Token does not have the privilege for this request.",
  "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
  "errorCode": "AUTH-010"
}
```

altghu my token is work good for GET Hub, GET Top folder etc..
on the decomentation i can see "app only" , what does it mean?

any other API retrive all project details like adress, start-end date, project_type ?

thanks.

follow the decomentation

Answer (score 0):

I use :

[data:read] instead of [account:read] token.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is brought by not setting the correct scope: **account:read** for the access token.

```
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/
```

This requires this scope: `account:read`. Kindly, set it when generating the authentication access token you are using when you try hitting the endpoint.